# Unexpected Class.getMethod behaviour

Tags: java, reflection

A while ago I had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894740/any-solution-for-class-getmethod-reflection-and-autoboxing) when using Class.getMethod and autoboxing, and it made sense to implement this in your own lookup algorithm. But what really confused me a little was that the following is not working either:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public String doSomething(Serializable s)
    {
        return s.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException
    {
        TestClass tc = new TestClass();
        Method m = tc.getClass().getMethod("doSomething", String.class);
    }
}
```

String.class implements the Serializable interface and I really expected it to be included in the lookup method. <strike>Do I have to consider this in my own lookup algorithms as well?</strike>

**EDIT**: I did read the Javadoc, *so let me emphasise the second part of the question*: And if so do you have suggestions on how to do that fast (I already had to add some custom matching and converting algorithms and I don't want it to get too slow)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your edit, you can make use of [`Class#isAssignableFrom()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29). Here's a basic kickoff example (leaving obvious (runtime) exception handling aside):

```
package com.stackoverflow.q2169497;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Test {

    public String doSomething(Serializable serializable) {
        return serializable.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test test = new Test();
        for (Method method : test.getClass().getMethods()) {
            if ("doSomething".equals(method.getName())) {
                if (method.getParameterTypes()[0].isAssignableFrom(String.class)) {
                    System.out.println(method.invoke(test, "foo"));
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This should print `foo` to stdout.

Answer (score 4):

The javadoc for [Class.getMethod](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) is very explicit:

> The parameterTypes parameter is an
>   array of Class  objects that identify
>   the method's formal parameter types,
>   in declared order.

It offers no scope for subtypes.

Answer (score 1):

`getMethod` isn't meant to find methods which are *compatible* with the given parameter types - it's meant to find methods with *exactly* the given parameter types.

You'd need to call `getMethods()` to find all the methods, then filter by name and number of parameters, then work out which of those are actually applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you call `getMethod` with `String.class`? Method signatures are exactly mapped. It doesn't make any sense to look up a method by the same criteria as if you will call them.