# Using java.lang.reflect.getMethod with polymorphic methods

Tags: java, reflection, polymorphism

Consider the following snippet:

```
public class ReflectionTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ReflectionTest test = new ReflectionTest();
        String object = new String("Hello!");

        // 1. String is accepted as an Object
        test.print(object);

        // 2. The appropriate method is not found with String.class
        try {
            java.lang.reflect.Method print
                = test.getClass().getMethod("print", object.getClass());
            print.invoke(test, object);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(); // NoSuchMethodException!
        }
    }

    public void print(Object object) {
        System.out.println(object.toString());
    }

}
```

`getMethod()` is obviously unaware that a `String` could be fed to a method that expects an `Object` (indeed, it's documentation says that it looks for *method with the specified name and exactly the same formal parameter types*).

Is there a straightforward way to find methods reflectively, like `getMethod()` does, but taking polymorphism into account, so that the above reflection example could find the `print(Object)` method when queried with `("print", String.class)` parameters?

Comment: I head a similar problem in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169497/unexpected-class-getmethod-behaviour and there wasn't a way around doing it with iterating over all arguments and calling isAssignableFrom

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [reflection tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html)

suggest the use of `Class.isAssignableFrom()` sample for finding `print(String)`

```
    Method[] allMethods = c.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method m : allMethods) {
        String mname = m.getName();
        if (!mname.startsWith("print") {
            continue;
        }
        Type[] pType = m.getGenericParameterTypes();
        if ((pType.length != 1)
            || !String.class.isAssignableFrom(pType[0].getClass())) {
            continue;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do this is via java.beans.Statement or java.beans.Expression. Does all these hard yards for you.

> getMethod() is obviously unaware that
>   a String  could be fed to a method
>   that expects an Object

'Unaware' is a strange way to put it. `getMethod()` adheres to its specification. You have to supply the formal parameters, not the types of the actual arguments.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, it is how I invoke method using reflection with **multiple** parameters without giving their types.

```
public class MyMethodUtils {
    /**
     * Need to pass parameter classes
     */
    public static Object invoke(Object invoker, String methodName, Object[] parameters, Class[] parameterClasses) throws Exception {
        Method method = invoker.getClass().getMethod(methodName, parameterClasses);
        Object returnValue = method.invoke(invoker, parameters);
        return returnValue;
    }

    /**
     * No need to pass parameter classes
     */
    public static Object invoke(Object invoker, String methodName, Object[] parameters) throws Exception {
        Method[] allMethods = invoker.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
        Object returnValue = null;
        boolean isFound = false;
        for (Method m : allMethods) {
            String mname = m.getName();
            if (!mname.equals(methodName)) {
                continue;
            }
            Class[] methodParaClasses = m.getParameterTypes();
            for (int i = 0; i < methodParaClasses.length; i++) {
                Class<?> parameterClass = parameters[i].getClass();
                Class<?> methodParaClass = methodParaClasses[i];
                boolean isAssignable = methodParaClass.isAssignableFrom(parameterClass);
                if (!isAssignable) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            returnValue = m.invoke(invoker, parameters);
            isFound = true;
        }
        if (!isFound) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot find such method");
        }

        return returnValue;
    }

}
```

**Sample Usage:**

```
    MyMethodUtils.invoke(student, "setNameAndMarks", new Object[] { "John", marks }, new Class[] { String.class, Collection.class });
    MyMethodUtils.invoke(student, "setNameAndMarks", new Object[] { "John", marks });
```

However, for the method `invoke(Object invoker, String methodName, Object[] parameters)`, it is possible to invoke wrong method if the signature is ambiguous. For example, if there is two methods for the invoker:

```
public void setNameAndMarks(String name, Collection<Integer> marks);
public void setNameAndMarks(String name, ArrayList<Integer> marks);
```

Passing the following parameter may invoke wrong method

```
setNameAndMarks("John", new ArrayList<Integer>());
```