# Java getMethod with subclass parameter

Tags: java, reflection, polymorphism, subclass

I'm writing a library that uses reflection to find and call methods dynamically.  Given just an object, a method name, and a parameter list, I need to call the given method as though the method call were explicitly written in the code.

I've been using the following approach, which works in most cases:

```
static void callMethod(Object receiver, String methodName, Object[] params) {
    Class<?>[] paramTypes = new Class<?>[params.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
        paramTypes[i] = params[i].getClass();
    }
    receiver.getClass().getMethod(methodName, paramTypes).invoke(receiver, params);
}
```

However, when one of the parameters is a *subclass* of one of the supported types for the method, the reflection API throws a `NoSuchMethodException`.  For example, if the receiver's class has `testMethod(Foo)` defined, the following fails:

```
receiver.getClass().getMethod("testMethod", FooSubclass.class).invoke(receiver, new FooSubclass());
```

even though this works:

```
receiver.testMethod(new FooSubclass());
```

How do I resolve this?  If the method call is hard-coded there's no issue - the compiler just uses the overloading algorithm to pick the best applicable method to use.  It doesn't work with reflection, though, which is what I need.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide an SSCCE?

Comment: The issue is with polymorphism, rather than overloading.
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083786/using-java-lang-reflect-getmethod-with-polymorphic-methods

Comment: you can't invoke a function with reflection without specifying formal parameter type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java getMethod with superclass parameters in method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580665/java-getmethod-with-superclass-parameters-in-method)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bit longer than what you started with, but this does what you asked for... and a little more besides - for example, callMethod(receiver, "voidMethod") where voidMethod takes no arguments also works.

```
static void callMethod(Object receiver,
      String methodName, Object... params) {
  if (receiver == null || methodName == null) {
    return;
  }
  Class<?> cls = receiver.getClass();
  Method[] methods = cls.getMethods();
  Method toInvoke = null;
  methodLoop: for (Method method : methods) {
    if (!methodName.equals(method.getName())) {
      continue;
    }
    Class<?>[] paramTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
    if (params == null && paramTypes == null) {
      toInvoke = method;
      break;
    } else if (params == null || paramTypes == null
        || paramTypes.length != params.length) {
      continue;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < params.length; ++i) {
      if (!paramTypes[i].isAssignableFrom(params[i].getClass())) {
        continue methodLoop;
      }
    }
    toInvoke = method;
  }
  if (toInvoke != null) {
    try {
      toInvoke.invoke(receiver, params);
    } catch (Exception t) {
      t.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This would look much better if you splitted the part that find the correct method (since that's what doesn't work correctly with subclasses) and the invocation of the method itself (that works flawlessly once you've got the right Method).

Comment: This is almost too genius, know what I mean?  It worked though, when nothing else did, so the example was very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
receiver.testMethod(new FooSubclass());
even though this works:
```

If your `testMethod` function has parameter of `FooSuperClass` type:

```
 public void testMethod(FooSuperClass object){}
```

then,  while you are trying to get a *matching* method with reflection: `getClass().getMethod("testMethod", FooSubclass.class)` will result in `NoSuchMethodException`. Because this `getMethod(String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes` function returns a `Method` object which is a public member method with the given `name` where `parameterTypes` parameter is an array of Class objects that identify the method's ***formal parameter types***. There is actually no such method is declared with signature `testMedthod(FooSubClass object)` as the formal parameter type of the function is `FooSuperClass`. So, the correct invocation is:

```
receiver.getClass().getMethod("testMethod", FooSuperClass.class)
                        .invoke(receiver, new FooSubclass());
```

**or**, passing the super class by calling `SubClass.class.getSuperClass()` as follows:

```
receiver.getClass().getMethod("testMethod", FooSubClass.class.getSuperclass())
                            .invoke(receiver, new FooSubclass());
```

**or**, changing the method signature to: `public void testMethod(FooSubClass object){}` and then invoke as you are doing now:

```
receiver.getClass().getMethod("testMethod", FooSubclass.class)
                         .invoke(receiver, new FooSubclass());
```