# How can I get Java reflection to find a callable function?

Tags: java, reflection

I have an interface `ZipCodeServer` which the class `ZipCodeServerImpl` implements.

I also have an interface `ZipCodeList` which the class `ZipCodeListImpl` implements.

One of the functions that the `ZipCodeServer` interface requires is

```
public void initialise(ZipCodeList newlist) throws RemoteException;
```

Now as you can imagine, this works fine when I try to pass in a `ZipCodeListImpl` to the `initialise` function.

But when I try to do it via reflection (syntax is not correct, but basically I am passing in an array of only the class `ZipCodeListImpl`):

```
aZipCodeServer.getClass().getMethod("initialise", [aZipCodeListImpl.getClass()]);
```

I get the error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ZipCodeServerImpl.initialise(ZipCodeListImpl)
```

of course because the function expects a `ZipCodeList` parameter.

Thing is, this code has to be generic, so I have the list of parameters and the function name, but I have to find the function itself via reflection.

Comment: why are you using reflection? 99.99999999% it means you are *doing it wrong*, the other 0.00000001% of the time there is probably a better way anyway. Reflection isn't *Generics* using Generics is Generic! If it is for injection, look at using Guice instead.

Comment: @jarrod There has to be a better duplicate than that...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - there are, all over the general internet and this site!

Comment: @Jarrod I'll try and find a more appropriate one.

Comment: @jarrod Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886065/java-getmethod-with-subclass-parameter . Agree?

Comment: then close it back ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by *generics* in this case, but since the parameter type is `ZipCodeList`, you'll need to use the `Class` object for that as an argument to `getMethod`. If you don't have it, you can recursively traverse the class/interface hierarchy of the subclass, trying each as you go.

Answer (score 0):

Use java.beans.Expression:

```
new Expression(server, "initialise", new Object[] { list }).execute();
```

This should handle subtype relationships between formal parameters and actual arguments, as well as primitive-vs.-wrapper boxing/unboxing. It won't handle primitive widening though: see [this bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6945188).