# NoSuchMethodException thrown when method exists

Tags: java

I'm trying to create an instance of a class, based on the class and the parameters. The method used to create this class looks like so:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Plugin instantiatePlugin(Class clazz, Object... params) {
        try {
            Class plugin = pluginClasses.get(clazz);
            if (params.length > 0) {
                Class[] parameterTypes = new Class[params.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < parameterTypes.length; i++) {
                    parameterTypes[i] = params[i].getClass();
                }
                return (Plugin)plugin.getDeclaredConstructor(parameterTypes).newInstance(params);
            } else {
                return (Plugin)plugin.newInstance();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The error that I'm getting is the following:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: plugin.movement.WalkRunPlugin.(com.rr.server.entity.mob.player.Player)

When trying to call the declared constructor. Here's what I'm passing to the method: `instantiatePlugin(MovementPlugin.class, this);`

Where `this` is the instance of the `Player` class, which extends `Mob`.

Here's the `only` constructor in my `WalkRunPlugin` example:

```
public WalkRunPlugin(Mob mob) {
    this.mob = mob;
}
```

Considering Mob is abstract, and Player extends mob, Player is a Mob, So I see no reason why this shouldn't work.

This seems to be because the reflection method is expecting the type of Player and not the type of Mob, however a Player is not the only Mob. So I need to find a way to accept subclasses of a super-class in this method. 
Tips?

Compilable example:

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example();
    }

    private Example() {
        try {
            Class clazz = Plugin.class;
            clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(Player.class).newInstance(new Player());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static abstract class Mob {

    }

    public static class Player extends Mob {

    }

    public static class Plugin {
        Mob m;

        Plugin(Mob m) {
            this.m = m;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a short but complete example?

Comment: @JonSkeet - One moment, I'll post one.

Comment: have you cleaned before compiling?

Comment: Posted a compilable example.

Comment: @gurghet - Yes. That's always my first step when things get strange

Comment: Will you ever have multiple parameters, and multiple matching constructors? Because this is pretty simple for a *single* parameter - but when you end up having to perform overload resolution yourself, that's pretty ugly.

Comment: Reflection doesn't support polymorphic arguments.

Comment: replace Player by Mob in Plugin constructor. When using the constructor, use a cast e.g. (Mob)player

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26153639/how-can-i-get-java-reflection-to-find-a-callable-function?lq=1

Comment: @JonSkeet - The amount of parameters for each plugin is user specific, and can be whatever the user wants them to be. In this case `movement plugin` needs to operate for all mobs. Should I just create a constructor for a `Player` and a `Npc` etc? (Both mob types)

Comment: @Christian.tucker: It depends if you want to go to all the trouble of performing the same sort of overload resolution (potentially including boxing!) that the Java compiler does. It really won't be fun, to be honest...

Comment: @jon I think I'll just stick with multiple constructors for now, it doesn't really hurt anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [`getConstructor` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-) will not find the constructor because it will only find an exact match of parameter types.

> The constructor to reflect is the public constructor of the class represented by this Class object whose formal parameter types match those specified by parameterTypes.

It won't work like the compiler, which will consider a possible widening reference conversion of `Player` to `Mob` to match the constructor.

You will need to find the proper `Constructor`.  Here is the best way I can think of:

Loop through all `Constructor`s returned by `getConstructors`.  Determine if all parameter types either match the types of arguments you have, or if they are superclasses of all the types of arguments you have.  You can access the parameter types of a `Constructor` with the `getParameterTypes()` method, which will access the `Class` objects associated with the parameter types.  Then you can use `isInstance(params[i])` (or `isAssignableFrom(params[i].getClass())`).  If all parameters match, then use that `Constructor`.

This can obviously get messy and very complicated, because you are doing a job the compiler normally does -- determining the correct constructor to call -- but for this exact purpose, one of the above solutions should be sufficient.  You should be able to find the `Constructor` that takes a `Mob`, even if you are given a `Player` instance, in the above way.

Comment: [Example with `Method` (apply logic to `Constructor`)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580665/java-getmethod-with-superclass-parameters-in-method?rq=1). `java.beans.*` also seems promising.