# Problem using model.getClass().getMethod in case of inheritance

Tags: java, reflection, inheritance

I'm following this [article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html) on Oracle Network to implement MVC when developing desktop applications.
I have a problem, though: I'm using an abstract *Directory* class extended by `SimpleDirectory` and `WildcardDirectory`. One of the model manager method accepts a Directory as argument:

```
public void addDirectoryDummy(Directory d){
    System.out.println("Hello!");
}
```

The abstract controller uses a setModelProperty to call this method:

```
protected void setModelProperty(String propertyName, Object newValue) {



    for (AbstractModel model: registeredModels) {
        try {

            Method method = model.getClass().
                getMethod(propertyName, new Class[] {
                                                  newValue.getClass()
                                              }
                         );

            method.invoke(model, newValue);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I call it from my actual controller like this:

```
public void dummy( Directory d){
    setModelProperty( BACKUP_DUMMY, d );
}
```

In my view I have:

```
this.controller.dummy( new SimpleDirectory(0,"ciao") );
```

I have the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: it.univpm.quickbackup.models.BackupManager.addDirectoryDummy(it.univpm.quickbackup.models.SimpleDirectory)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1605)
```

How do I solve this problem? I'm missing something in the usage of `getMethod`.

EDIT: I've read the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) and in `getMethod` it says

> The parameterTypes parameter is an array of Class objects that identify
>   the method's formal parameter types,
>   in declared order.

So I'm guessing that's the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
        Test test = new Test();
        Child child = new Child();

        // Your approach, which doesn't work
        try {
            test.getClass().getMethod("doSomething", new Class[] { child.getClass() });

        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
            System.out.println("This doesn't work");
        }

        // A working approach
        for (Method method : test.getClass().getMethods()) {
            if ("doSomething".equals(method.getName())) {
                if (method.getParameterTypes()[0].isAssignableFrom(child.getClass())) {
                    method.invoke(test, child);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("This works");

    }

    public void doSomething(Parent parent) {

    }
}

class Parent {

}

class Child extends Parent {

}
```

Comment: The problem this is a general controller. I can't do that, I need to know the class at runtime. And second of all, SimpleDirectory extends Directory so isn't there a solution when it comes to inheritance?

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169497/unexpected-class-getmethod-behaviour

Comment: tnx, I've read it but I don't think it's the same because he's talking about interfaces, I'm having trouble with inheritance. It doesn't seem to me that isAssignableFrom would solve my problem.

Comment: As soon as I go home I'll try and let you know.

Comment: `method.getParameterTypes()[0].isAssignableFrom(child.getClass())` can be written as `method.getParameterTypes()[0].isInstance(child)`

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.test;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Test test = new Test();
    Child child = new Child();

    // Your approach, which doesn't work
    try {
        Method method = test.getClass().getMethod("doSomething", new Class[] { child.getClass().getSuperclass() });
        method.invoke(test, child);
        System.out.println("This works");
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
        System.out.println("This doesn't work");
    }

    // A working approach
    for (Method method : test.getClass().getMethods()) {
        if ("doSomething".equals(method.getName())) {
        if (method.getParameterTypes()[0].isAssignableFrom(child.getClass())) {
            method.invoke(test, child);
            System.out.println("This works");
        }
        }
    }

    }

    public void doSomething(Parent parent) {

    }
}

class Parent {

}

class Child extends Parent {

}
```

You need add .getSuperclass() to child