# Last Variable argument not optional when calling method using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to invoke a method using reflection

```
Method mi = TestInterface.class.getMethod("TestMethod", java.lang.String.class,java.lang.String.class,java.lang.String.class,java.lang.Object[].class);
```

this method has 3 mandatory string arguments, the last argument, which is the variable argument is optional.

However when I invoke this method as below.

```
mi.invoke(new TestImplementation(), new Object[]{"arg1", "arg2","arg3"});
```

then it gives me an error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments`

but the last arguement should be optional right?
or this doesn't work in case of invoking methods using reflection??

Code:

```
public interface TestInterface {
    public void TestMethod(String str, String str1, String str2, Object... objects);
} 

public class TestImplementation implements TestInterface {
    public void TestMethod(String str1, String str2, String str3, Object... objects) {
        // ....
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
    // works perfectly
    TestInterface obj = new TestImplementation();
    obj.TestMethod("str", "str1", "str2");
    // doesn't work
    Method mi = TestInterface.class.getMethod("TestMethod", java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class,
            java.lang.String.class);
    mi.invoke(new TestImplementation(), new Object[] { "arg1", "arg2", "arg3" });
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is optional argument in Java?

Comment: What is the prototype of your method?

Comment: I think, you have to pass an empty `Object[]` as last argument.

Comment: without using reflection, if i simply invoke this method as below :      TestInterface obj = new TestImplementation();
  obj.TestMethod("str", "str1", "str2");                        then it works fine...but if i do the same using reflection...then it gives error..

Comment: What I mean is...the last variable argument normally is optional, but not in case when using reflection. or is there some work around?

Comment: @Hernal In Java no optional parameters. There is only overriding mechanism.

Comment: if not using reflection..i try this code..then it works perfectly fine...TestInterface obj = new TestImplementation(); obj.TestMethod("str", "str1", "str2"); here the last Object[] is optional..rite?

Comment: @Hemal Could you please show TestInterface and TestImplementation code?

Comment: Interface-------------------------------------------------------------public interface TestInterface {
 
 public void TestMethod(String str, String str1, String str2, Object ...objects);

}

Comment: Implementation--------------------------------------------------------public class TestImplementation implements TestInterface{
 public void TestMethod(String str1, String str2, String str3, Object ...objects) {
  ....
 }

}

Comment: Main Method-----------------------------------------------------------public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
  //works perfectly
  TestInterface obj = new TestImplementation();
  obj.TestMethod("str", "str1", "str2");
  
  //doesn't work
  Method mi = TestInterface.class.getMethod("TestMethod", java.lang.String.class,java.lang.String.class,java.lang.String.class);
  mi.invoke(new TestImplementation(), new Object[]{"arg1", "arg2","arg3"});
  
 }

Comment: So I was confuced by lexic you are used. In Java it called Varargs( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html )

Comment: glad we are clear now...so how can we make this work..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java don't exists optional parameters. You can only **override** methods or use [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

In your case of [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) you are **explicitly request** Method object with paramters: `String, String, String, Object[]`.

So you **must invoke** method with same parameters:

```
mi.invoke(new TestImplementation(), new Object[]{"arg1", "arg2","arg3", new Object[0]);
```

To understand your problem in general way see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600854/how-to-work-with-varargs-and-reflection).

Comment: Taky, incase if i try to find method with String, String, String, then it gives java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:...does that mean, variable argument is not optional when using reflection?

Comment: It means TestImplementation hasn't TestMethod(String, String, String). Mayby some base class has this method. Review this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737388/problem-using-model-getclass-getmethod-in-case-of-inheritance or pass correct class into the getMethod(...)

Comment: there is no base class which has TestMethod(String, String, String), but still if not using reflection we are able to call this method simple by TestInterface obj = new TestImplementation(); obj.TestMethod("str", "str1", "str2"); , but the same cannot be done using reflection, thats wht my point is...

Comment: In short the varargs is not optional using reflection...as I mentioned earlier??

Comment: No. It is implicit array of Object passing into the method. In Java level on runtime Object[] and Object... are the same.